# Масштабирование интерфейса юнити 2д

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я работаю над визуальной новеллой в юнити 2д. При попытке скомпилировать игру, интерфейс масштабировался неверно, и части интерфейса(слева и справа) вылезли вне дисплея. Как это можно решить?
P.S. Речь НЕ про UI(хотя и там тоже беда, но про ui обсуждений полно), а про изображения, и тот факт, что кусок интерфейса просто не влазит в экран. Буду благодарен, за помощь.

Comment: Вы пишете слова "изображение" (Image) и "интерфейс" (User Interface), но потом сразу уточняете, что речь не о UI (чем Image, например, является). Уточните, вы имеете ввиду "изображение", как компонент SpriteRenderer?

Comment: Простите, моя неточность. Проблема в том - что кусок интерфейса просто не попадет на экран. Скорее всего, дело в разрешении камеры, хотя я ее поставил в стоковые настойки, ничего не изменилось. Можете что-то посоветовать?

Comment: Советую делать по человечески. Интерфейс, который не UI это как овчарка, которая не собака.

Comment: Можете уточнить?

Comment: Как говорилось в одном из фильмов: Интерфейс в канвасе, детям мороженое, бабе цветы.

Comment: Александр, спасибо вам! Я неправильно организовал интерфейс. Напишите ваш ответ не как комментарий, отмечу правильным!

Comment: Лучше Вы сами напишите ответ. Такое тоже практикуется на сайте. Напишите ответ и обязательно наглядно продемонстрируйте иерархию. Это поможет другим, кто столкнется с подобным вопросом.